# Preventing an attribute field name from displaying in the Input app

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

Using the *Input* app, I want to hide a layer's attribute field from the user's smartphone view.  For example, there is no need for them to see the *fid*, as shown in the phone screenshot below.

I suspect that it's managed from within the QGIS > Layer Properties > Attribute Forms page, but nothing is apparent to me.  I've reviewed the *Mergin* and *Input* docs without success.  I'm using QGIS 3.24.1

How can I hide an attribute field in the *Input* app display?

Edit: My question is about *viewing* a field and its data.  I'm asking how to hide it completely from view.  The *fid* is a good example because it is for internal software use only, and is not user-editable.

[image]

Comment: Is this about digitizing, or viewing the data?

Comment: Thanks, it is for viewing the data; OP updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can customise this view by going to Layer Properties > Display. Within that, you can use some basic HTML tags, for example:

```
# fields
Box ID
```

You can also embed a photo preview (if you have a photo field:

```
# image
file:///[%@project_folder%]/[% "image_1" %]
```

For HTML, you can write something like this:

```
<p><strong>Notes:</strong>[% "notes" %]</p>
```

For more information, see:
https://merginmaps.com/docs/gis/features/#settings-for-mergin-maps-input-preview-panel

Comment: Thanks, but the *# fields* option does not work as you propose.  When I use it with two field names, Input responds with "No map tip available".

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled onto an answer...

From the QGIS *Layers* panel, select the layer and go to *Layer properties > Attributes Form > Available widgets* and select the field that to be hidden.  In my case, that field was *fid*.

On the right side, drop-down the *Widget Type* to *Hidden*.

Apply the change, then synchronize the Mergin project, and...

Voila!  The field no longer appears in the Input app.

[image]

Comment: If you only need some fields, it is even easier to change form from "autogenerate" to Drag and Drop Designer. There you can simply remove fields that you don't want to be visible.